# Cannot fetch array value in variable - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief Explanation:** I have fetched result in variable `res` using `**js**`.

Result of `res` on console is shown below.

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL6AR.png)

> **Requirement:** I want to get the value of `res` in angular variable. I have declared

`resarry = [];`

*When i do*

```
this.resarry = res;
console.log(this.resaary);
```

*Error coming* - **Cannot set property of 'resarray` undefined.**

`console.log(results); // no problem in this line
console.log(this.resarry); // giving error`

```
export class HomePage {
resarry = [];


constructor(){
     var connection = new JsStore.Instance();
              var dbName = 'Demo';
          connection.openDb(dbName);

          connection.select({
            from: Test1,
          }).then(function(res) {
         // results will be array of objects

            console.log(res,'results');
            this.resarry = results;
console.log(results); // no problem in this line
console.log(this.resarry); // giving error

          }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err, 'error');
            alert(err.message);
        });

}
}
```

Comment: if you use `function(res)` the scope of this is lost use arrow functions `(res) => {} `and you will not lose

Comment: try `resarry: any;` and in `constructor(){  this.resarry={}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: console.log(this.resaary) or console.log(this.resarray);; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
connection.select({
  from: Test1,
}).then(function(res) {
  // ...
});
```

to:

```
connection.select({
  from: Test1,
}).then(res => {
  // ...
});
```

Basically, `function() { ... }` can't access `this` from the outer scope, while arrow functions can. A more in-depth explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/965834).

Also, [arrow functions' docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: all right, but a little more description is necessary to know that focus of this got left in function(){} and not on () => {}

Comment: @mtizziani Right, I added minimal explanation. I feel like the official docs was clear enough but adding the gist of it won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

```
resarry:number[] = new Array();
```

will initialize an empty array which is not undefined.

you can set the type where your result is expected to be.

Comment: this doesn't help, its a focus problem on this

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.select({
         from: Test1,
      }).then(function(res) { // results will be array of objects
        console.log(res,'results');
        this.resarry = results; //  perhaps like that => this.resarry = res
        console.log(results); // i think, you should have an error on this line because **results** isn't a variable but a string in your console
        console.log(this.resarry); // giving error

      })
```

Comment: Please, follow the comments that i added in the code

Answer (score 0):

Because, the "this" meant to be the current function object. So the "this", you have used in the constructor is not the actual component

**Use Arrow function or**

```
constructor(){
     var connection = new JsStore.Instance();
              var dbName = 'Demo';
          connection.openDb(dbName);
     var $this = this;
          connection.select({
            from: Test1,
          }).then(function(res) {
         // results will be array of objects

            console.log(res,'results');
            $this.resarry = results;
console.log(results); // no problem in this line
console.log($this.resarry); // giving error

          }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err, 'error');
            alert(err.message);
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

User arrow functions as well as typescript types to validate things before assigning

```
export class HomePage {
    resarry: any[] = []; //--> resarry: any[] -> used to set the type as array
    constructor() {
        let connection = new JsStore.Instance(); //-> use Let insted of Var
        let dbName = 'Demo';
        connection.openDb(dbName);
        connection.select({
            from: "Test1",
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res)
                if (res.length > 0){
                    this.resarry = res;
                    console.log(this.resarry);
                    console.log("connection Successful with array objects");
                }else{
                    console.log("connection Successful  without array objects");
                }
        }), err => {
            console.log("connection error");
        };

    }
}
```